# Multiscroll.js and scroll inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am looking for solution of my problem contected with multiscroll.js plugin. I am creating a website - [demo](http://lab98.pl/4men/test) - and I need to allow user scroll photos inside last div (right column). I had to use multiscroll.js because the effect of scroll is necessary for me. Can anyone help me? :)

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: I can scroll the photos in the right column. What exactly is your problem? Also provide your html/css

Comment: I mean photo in last section - with instagram.